# kill subprocess spawned by spawnProcess in twisted doesn't work

Tags: python, process, twisted

all

I start a process using spawnProcess and want to kill when my certain Factory stops.

something I wrote like these

---

```
p = SomeProtocol(ProcessProtocol)

reactor.spawnProcess(p, 'twistd', ['twistd', '-y', 'anotherMain.py'], {})
```

---

```
class Factory(ServerFactory):
...

    def StopFactory(self):
        # which is the p above
        p.transport.signalProcess("KILL")
```

I thought the subprocess will be killed which is not.

I tried using p.transport.signalProcess("KILL") some other place, and it works.

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be because `twistd` daemonizes `anotherMain.py`. After `anotherMain.py` becomes a daemon `twistd` process exits. So `anotherMain.py` isn't really a subprocess of your main process.

Try to add `-n` option:

```
reactor.spawnProcess(p, 'twistd', ['twistd', '-ny', 'anotherMain.py'], {})
```

Comment: Hmm.  I want to upvote this, but I am conflicted.  Why shouldn't a program launch `twistd` like this?  It seems perfectly valid to me.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Thanks. Deleted second part of the answer.